# Android app scan Nordic device but can't find the device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on Nordic NRF52840 periodic advertising and scan the device with Android app Android 10. I ask a question yesterday then I rewrite my code using the tutorial on the internet, basically my app is very easy, press the button then the app will scan and print the ble device on log, but I still can't find my device I don't know what's wrong with my code I add a ton of permission in Manifest.xml but nothing changed I still can't find the device I want.                    Update: I can find some device,but not my device, I still can't find my device there are a few question I want to ask

1. I can't find my device, but can find other device.
2. how to stop scanning, I add a button to stop scanning, but it won't stop.
3. how to get device name, when I call getName() error pop up and the app closed
   [getName error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Almiy.jpg)

> AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tryble_scanner">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" 
 />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" 
android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" 
android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TryBle_scanner">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tryble_scanner;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter  = null;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS = 0;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 1;
private boolean mScanning = false;
private Handler mHandler = null;

private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
                //super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                BluetoothDevice btdevice = result.getDevice();
                Log.d("BLE", btdevice.getAddress());
            }
            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                Log.d("BLE", "error");
            }
};
private  ScanCallback mLeScanCallback2=new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.d("BLE","scan stop");
    }
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.d("BLE","stop scan failed");
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
}

public void stop_scan(View view) {
    Log.d("Ble","scan stop pressed");
//        mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback2);
mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(mLeScanCallback2);
}

public void onBtnScan(View view) {
    Log.i("Btn","get click");
    checkBTPermission();
    String[] names=new String[]{"Auden test"};
    List<ScanFilter> filters=null;
    if(names != null){
        filters=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String name:names){
            ScanFilter filter=new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(name).build();
            filters.add(filter);
        }
    }
    if(mBluetoothLeScanner==null){
        Log.i("BLE","could not get scanner");
    }else{
        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);  //filters,scanSettings,mLeScanCallback
    }
}

private void checkBTPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if(pc!=0){
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
        }else {
            Log.d("BLE","checkBT permission");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried scanning without any filters and scan settings? Scan settings and filters are optional parameters, so you can pass null for them.

Comment: I have tried without any filter and nothing happened too

Comment: Then there are 2 possibilities. 1 is that the location service of your phone is off. 2 is, as @MichaelKotzjan mentioned in his answer you need to request one of the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. Because I don't see in your code that you neither check the location service state nor implement any permission result handler.

Comment: @JayLin1119 Please also go to your device settings -> Apps -> Your App and check the given permissions there

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan iI check my permission in setting, and there is permission for location

Comment: @Kozmotronik I have added the permission request in checkBtpermission function, the request did pop up but still nothing

Comment: @JayLin1119 and where do you handle the permission result in your code? Is the location service of the phone turned on?

Comment: Do you get scan failed error or you get nothing at all?

Comment: @Kozmotronik my location service is turned on, handle the permission result? I thought I only need to call the requestPermission.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I got D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=4 mScannerId=0, this line in Run window

Comment: @JayLin1119 I see, handling the permission result may not make sense if your application is for hobby. But if otherwise you need to handle the user denial on permission when the permissions request are resulted either via `onRequestPermissionsResult` or `ActivityResultLauncher`. Cuold you share your logcat while starting the scanning?

Comment: @Kozmotronik 
https://imgur.com/a/5wNMOj2

Comment: @Kozmotronik I am new to the android develop there are some error when I run the app I don't know what the error mean, does this effect my app?

Comment: What kind of errors? Share them if possible, it may help for debugging.

Comment: @Kozmotronik the error is in the imgur link I send, The error is "Fail to get file list" "getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array" "Fail to get file list com.example.tryble_scanner"

Comment: by the way how to highlight the text like you did in the comment

Comment: @JayLin1119 I don't think that those exceptions affect the Bluetooth library. There must be something else missing in your project. Use (`) to highlight the words as code in the beginning end end of the code, word, or code section.

Answer (score 1):

You do indeed declare the permissions in your manifest file, but keep in mind that some of them are so called runtime permissions. You need to ask the user of your app for the permission at runtime. The [Request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) site of the Android Developer Guide gives you more information on that topic.

You basically need a permissions callback to handle the users response:

```
// Register the permissions callback, which handles the user's response to the
// system permissions dialog. Save the return value, an instance of
// ActivityResultLauncher, as an instance variable.
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(new RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // features requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
            // decision.
        }
    });
```

You also need to actually ask the user for the permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // You can use the API that requires the permission.
    performAction(...);
} else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(...)) {
    // In an educational UI, explain to the user why your app requires this
    // permission for a specific feature to behave as expected. In this UI,
    // include a "cancel" or "no thanks" button that allows the user to
    // continue using your app without granting the permission.
    showInContextUI(...);
} else {
    // You can directly ask for the permission.
    // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION);
}
```

The one permission that's most likely missing is the **Location** permission. [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android11-or-lower) part of the Developer Guide lists the required permissions for BLE on Android < 11.

Please also use a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=de&gl=US) to verify that your device actually advertises itself.

Comment: Hi Michael Kotzjan thanks for the tech support I added the permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION when button clicked but still nothing happened, I have check the nRF connect app which show that my nordic device is advertising.

Comment: Could you update your question and add your changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you're done with permissions and the rest, probably you are instantiating the `BluetoothAdapter` in an incorrect way. Try instantiating it like the following example in your main activity's `onCreate` method:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    mHandler = new Handler();

}
```

---

### Update for test

Well I had to make a new basic project to test it. I'll share te manifest and activity code, also the output. I've tested it on my Android 11 installed mobile. Note that I've removed all scan filters.

**manifest**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.karalama">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Karalama"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Karalama.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**

```java
package com.example.karalama;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.karalama.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter  = null;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;
    private boolean mScanning = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        com.example.karalama.databinding.ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        Log.d("BLE", "onCreate: Bluetoothadapter null"+(mBluetoothAdapter == null));
        mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkBTPermission();
                String[] names=new String[]{"Auden test"};
                List<ScanFilter> filters=null;
                if(names != null){
                    filters=new ArrayList<>();
                    for(String name:names){
                        ScanFilter filter=new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(name).build();
                        filters.add(filter);
                    }
                }
                if(mBluetoothLeScanner==null){
                    Log.i("BLE","could not get scanner");
                }else{
                    mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    private final ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
            //super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            BluetoothDevice btdevice = result.getDevice();
            Log.d("BLE", "Found -> "+btdevice.getAddress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Log.d("BLE", "error");
        }
    };

    private void checkBTPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if(pc!=0){
                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
            }else {
                Log.d("BLE","checkBT permission");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The logcat output**

```
I/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:1130983): avc: denied { ioctl } for uid=10254 path="/dev/kgsl-3d0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15422 ioctlcmd=945 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c254,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1 app=com.example.karalama
I/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:1130984): avc: denied { read write } for uid=10254 path="/dev/kgsl-3d0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15422 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c254,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1 app=com.example.karalama
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=6 mScannerId=0
D/BLE: Found -> C8:FD:19:7F:5A:7D
D/BLE: Found -> 5F:EE:47:E9:F3:A3
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:B5:D3:5D
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:8B:C1:98
D/BLE: Found -> 40:94:41:26:D2:D6
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:8A:A9:AB
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:8B:C1:98
D/BLE: Found -> 5F:EE:47:E9:F3:A3
D/BLE: Found -> 4B:A2:87:44:4C:79
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:8A:A9:AB
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:8B:C1:98
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:B5:D3:5D
D/BLE: Found -> 40:94:41:26:D2:D6
D/BLE: Found -> 4B:A2:87:44:4C:79
D/BLE: Found -> C8:FD:19:7F:5A:7D
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:B5:D3:5D
D/BLE: Found -> D4:36:39:8B:C1:98
D/BLE: Found -> 7A:0F:6B:DD:EC:FB
```

### Update 2 - Get rid of the "getName" error

```java
@Override
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
    //super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    BluetoothDevice btdevice = result.getDevice();

    // The device may not have a name and getName may return null. Fix it in the following way
    String name = btdevice.getName() == null ? "No name" : btdevice.getName();
    Log.d("BLE", name+" - "+btdevice.getAddress());
}
```

Comment: Thank for the tech support, I will check if this work on monday because the device is at the company

Comment: I run the app and still can't scan my device.

Comment: @JayLin1119 I've updated the answer. I created a test project and used mostly your code for bluetooth operation. Check it out.

Comment: HI @Kozmotronik I got lots of error on navigation part, Is there anything I need to implement?

Comment: What kind of errors? Let me see the errors. I did not see any navigation code in your activity?

Comment: So it shows `cannot resolve symbol navigation`

Comment: Did you copied my whole example code as it is? If so, you should've adapted only the related parts into your code. Got it? Because you only need the BLE related code and nothing have to do with UI code parts.

Comment: Just finish modify, I will try this tomorrow because my nordic board was at the company, If I still can't scan anything I might have to look into nordic's setting

Comment: Ok. In case you can't get it worked, please update your question with the latest code you tried.

Comment: how to update my question should I ask a new question or just edit this one?

Comment: Do you managed to scan and find your device? If you have a new question you must ask it as a new question. But if you still have problems related to this question and the answers haven't resolved your problem then you can update this question with further infofmation that can help the developers to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I have update my question  I can find other device, but not my device

Comment: @JayLin1119 I've noted that your NRF module is Bluetooth 5.2. Now did you make any configuration on that module e. g. using AT commands?

Comment: @JayLin1119 may be you should make a test procedure first using the [Nordic's guide](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/ug_gsg_ncs52/UG/gsg/test_mobile.html)

Comment: Hi @Kozmotronik  So I am using nrf connect sdk v2.0.0 there is an example called periodic_adv which advertising a period of time all I edit is the advertising time.

Comment: Hi @Kozmotronik So I tried the test procedure I can connect, but it seems like the tutorial is a little out of date there are no `Enable Service` button, I can't receive the text I send in the termite

Answer (score -1):

you can take help from this link
https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/
if this still not works for use than u can use scan library
https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library